# NodeJS Express AMP form req.body. POST undefined, GET success

Tags: node.js

NodeJS, AMP-form, TLS/SSL, Nginx, npm, HTTP/2
all Least Version.

---

### POST

---

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parsre');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({true}); // tried false 
app.use(bodyParser.json()); // tried text(), json({type:*})

app.post('/post', function(req, res) {
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
    console.log('sent the name ' + req.body.name);
    console.log(util.inspect(req.body));
    console.log('request ' + req.query);
    res.json('Yo' + req.body.name);
});
```

Shell Console.log result Undefined

```
sent the name undefined
{}
request /vote?__amp_source_origin=https%3A%2F%2Fexample.com
```

Browser Console Success

```
Yo tanaka
```

HTML no doubt

```
Powered by AMP ⚡ HTML – Version
<form method="post" action-xhr="https://example.com/post" target="_top" novalidate="">
    <input type="text" name="name" value="a" placeholder="Name..." required="">
    <input type="submit" value="Subscribe" disabled="">
</form>

vote?__amp_source_origin=https%3A%2F%2Fexample.com  200 fetch
preview Yo tanka
response Yo tanaka
```

---

### GET

---

```
Need not Body-Parser.
//var bodyParser = require('body-parsre');
//app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({true}); // tried false 
//app.use(bodyParser.json()); // tried text(), json({type:*})

// Use req.request
app.get('/post', function(req, res) {
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
    console.log('sent the name ' + req.query);
    console.log('request ' + req.query);
    res.json('Yo' + req.query);
});
```

Form method get

```
<form method="get" action-xhr="https://example.com/post" target="_top" novalidate="">
```

Shell Console.log result

```
sent the name tanaka
{name: tanaka}
request [/vote?__amp_source_origin=https%3A%2F%2Fexample.com,
         {name:tanaka}]
```

Browser Console Success

```
Yo tanaka
```

I wanna POST.
I think body-parser Cause.

```
npm list --depth=0
ds@1.0.0 /usr/local/src/ds
├── body-parser@1.17.1
├── cookie-session@2.0.0-beta.1 extraneous
├── express@4.15.2
├── express-session@1.15.2 extraneous
├── helmet@3.5.0
├── mongodb@2.2.25
├── mongoose@4.9.2 extraneous
├── nunjucks@3.0.0
├── safe-regex@1.1.0 extraneous
└── session@0.1.0 extraneous
```

body-parser Least Version
https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser

Is BODYPARSER and AMPFORM incompatible with each other?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The amp-form component actually sends data with the enctype `multipart/form-data` so it can't be parsed using body-parser. They recommend using busboy, multiparty, formidable, or multer to handle multipart bodies. Here's an example using [multer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer#readme):

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({true});
app.use(bodyParser.json());

var multer  = require('multer');
var multipart = multer();

app.post('/post', multipart.fields([]), function (req, res) {
    res.setHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*.ampproject.org');
    res.setHeader('AMP-Access-Control-Allow-Source-Origin', 'http://' + req.headers.host);
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Expose-Headers', 'AMP-Access-Control-Allow-Source-Origin');

    console.log('sent the name ' + req.body.name);
    console.log(util.inspect(req.body));
    console.log('request ' + req.query);

    res.json('Yo' + req.body.name);
});
```

You'll also need to make those header changes to avoid AMP validation errors.

Answer (score 3):

I think, the problem is CORS, And the json is write like this: **res.json("Yo")**

```
   app.post('/post', function(req, res) {
         res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
         res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type,Content-Length, Authorization, Accept,X-Requested-With");
         res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods","PUT,POST,GET,DELETE,OPTIONS");
         console.log('sent the name ' + req.body['name']);
         console.log('sent the name ' + req.body[0]);
         console.log('sent the name ' + req.body.name);
         console.log('sent the name ' + req.body.test); // input name test
         console.log(util.inspect(req.body));
        res.json('Yo');
        });
```

Comment: @まめたろう, Do you try it

Comment: res.json is 200 and no error, but sent the name undefined. and I tried headers.

Comment: @まめたろう, so sorry, I have no idea! it's too strange